# Net core equivalent of Castle Windsor ResolveAll

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, castle-windsor

I trying to move my old my NetFramwork project made with Castle Windsor to netcore. I'm trying to replace this nuget package with the **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** package but i don't find an equivalent for convert this code:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IInterface1>>().ImplementedBy<Class1>().Named(nameof(v1)));
 container.Register(Component.For<IInterface1>>().ImplementedBy<Class2>().Named(nameof(v2)));
```

and the resolve all using:

```
 kernel.ResolveAll(IInterface1);
```

Is there a way to do this using **IServiceProvider**?

Comment: https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-inject-all-instances-of-a-service-interface-64b37b43fdc8 - I believe you can just resolve by wrapping the service type in an `IEnumerable` and requesting that for injection. Are you explicitly calling `ResolveAll` with Windsor?

Comment: yes i'm using  `ResolveAll` because return an array . then  for each element in the array i call a specific method :
`var elements= kernel.ResolveAll(IInterface1);
foreach (dynamic e in elements)
`

Comment: @TerryTucker `.GetServices<TService>()` extension method on `IServiceProvider`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.GetServices<TService>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservices?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetServices__1_System_IServiceProvider_) extension method on `IServiceProvider`

```
IEnumerable<IInterface1> variable = service.GetServices<IInterface1>().
```